# how to loop through table and set cell equal to an incremented value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, parameters, auto-increment

I have a table of Users and if the is companyID that is input is equal to the companyID the User their name is shown and all the other names are shown as XXXXX. I need a way to set it to "Name"(literally the word name) and then an incremented number for how ever many there are.

```
    select  
    case when t1.CompanyID = @id then t1.name else 
    (
    'XXXXX'
    )
    end as Name
```

with input 148 shows

[image]

i want to show this, and so on for more names(name3, name4, etc..):

[image]

Comment: Your images are missing.. Update it

Comment: is it better now? they show up for me on two different computers

Comment: How many users total typical output. 200 ish

Comment: How many rows are returned

Comment: idk about 70 for now but will be much more, if you can expand on @pholochitairze answer that would be great

Answer (score 0):

With `foo` being the name of your table, then this works (see [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30d06/1/2)) :

```
SET @id = 142;
SET @i = 0;
select  
    companyID,
    CASE WHEN foo.CompanyID = @id 
        THEN foo.name 
        ELSE (Concat('Name',@i := @i+1))
    END as Name
FROM foo;
```

Comment: this should work but it is giving me an incorrect syntax at :     maybe it is because im using sqlserver?

Comment: If you are using sql server, why did you tag `mysql` ? ^^ I think the problem then is that variables are not declared. I'll edit soon.

Comment: i declared the i  to check it, and your right i apologize i must have done it by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please.

```
select [CompanyID], 
case when([CompanyID]=@Id) then  'Name' + 
convert(nvarchar,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name DESC))  else Name end as Name
from [dbo].[Table_1]
order by [CompanyID]
```

Comment: why did u put when name = xxxx? it will never equal that.  and u ignored that fact that i am taking in an input of a company id that i need to match with the Name

Comment: but i was able to use the rownumber instead so thanks